# How to connect access database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have access database file with 7 tables in it but I don't know how to connect and show all tables, If some one can help me?

this is my code but it doesn't show anything

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    String connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Tables.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    string sql  = "SELECT Clients  FROM Tables";
    conn.ConnectionString = connection;
    conn.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    //conn.Close();                               
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: And what is the error this code is throwing? **Please *edit* the question with that information.**

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6fde18c2-3e82-4a75-acf5-9aa5dd2165c2/?

Comment: Use `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` instead?

Comment: @AlvinWong - That would mean his software would not function as a 64-bit process since that provider is not supported on 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: I used Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 it doesn't work and then I tried 12.0.

Comment: I used 4.0 but it didn't help then I used the 12.0

Comment: Well, I suppose it's safe to say that we can focus on the connection string. Unless you can provide the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 18):

Try this code,

```
public void ConnectToAccess()
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new 
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    // TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
    // additional required properties for your database.
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        @"Data source= C:\Documents and Settings\username\" +
        @"My Documents\AccessFile.mdb";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Insert code to process data.
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That only works for Access Databases older than Access 2007

Comment: but you can change it for instance in ms.access 2010 we use this one : string connetionString = null;
                connetionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
                                  (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + file;

Answer (score 6):

You are building a DataGridView on the fly and set the DataSource for it. That's good, but then do you add the DataGridView to the Controls collection of the hosting form?

```
this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
```

By the way the code is a bit confused

```
String connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Tables.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
string sql  = "SELECT Clients  FROM Tables";
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection))
{
     conn.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
     using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,conn))
     {
         adapter.Fill(ds);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
         // Of course, before addint the datagrid to the hosting form you need to 
         // set position, location and other useful properties. 
         // Why don't you create the DataGrid with the designer and use that instance instead?
         this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
     }
}
```

**EDIT** After the comments below it is clear that there is a bit of confusion between the file name (TABLES.ACCDB) and the name of the table CLIENTS.
[The SELECT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) is defined (in its basic form) as

```
 SELECT field_names_list FROM _tablename_
```

so the correct syntax to use for retrieving all the clients data is

```
 string sql  = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
```

where the `*` means -> all the fields present in the table

Comment: Thank you Steve, Im having an error adaper.Fill(ds); Th Microsoft Access Database engine cannot fine the imput table or query 'Tables'.Make sure it exist and that its name is spelled correctly.

Comment: The error seems clear to me. Do you have a table named `Tables` in your Tables.accdb? Or are you confusing the name of the file for the datatable?

Comment: The tables is right but I'm thinking, when I try to connect client table from file in select Clients from Tables something I'm doing wrong, oh I don't know this stuff. Even when I try to explain I don't know very well

Comment: If you open your Tables.accdb file with MS-Access do you see a table names `Tables` or do you see a table named `Clients`?

Comment: file name in Access database is 'Tables' and it has 7 tables Clients, Tasks, Projects, Developers etc.

Comment: Yep when I open Tables.accdb I see Clients and other tables.

Comment: Now It's not showing the table but adding another gridview

Comment: Do you have already defined the DataGridView with the designer? If yes then remove the `DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();` line and use the nema of the one already defined using the designer.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your help, it is working, but I have another question, where can I read more(a link) about tables, because I have different tables and I have to show them as well.

Comment: All right, I am glad that you find my answer helpful and correct. I think you should start with some basic SQL (see the link in my answer) and then search for a Tutorial on ADO.NET.