# C# MS Access Database Connection System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sqlconnection

I am not sure if this problem has anything to do with my code or simply the way that my database is set up. Any pointers would be awesome!

This is the error message that I get:

[image]

I have gone to "Modify Connection" and used the 'Test Connection' tool and that says that it connects fine but when the actual program runs nothing happens and I get the error.

Here is my code:

```
    private void btnAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection CustomerInfo = new SqlConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\Cory\\Desktop\\DeluxWrapsWindows\\DeluxWrapsWindows\\DeluxWraps_DB.mdb");
    { 
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("Insert into CustomerInfo(LastName, FirstName, Email, PhoneNumber, Address, Instagram, CarMake, CarModel, AdditionalNotes) Values(@LastName, @Firstname, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @Instagram, @CarMake, @CarModel, @AdditionalNotes)", CustomerInfo);

     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instagram", txtInstagram.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carmake", txtCarMake.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarModel", txtCarModel.Text);
     xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdditionalNotes", txtAdditionalNotes.Text);

     CustomerInfo.Open();
     xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
     CustomerInfo.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Sqlconnection should only be used when trying to connect to a SQL server database. See this link to see more information about this kind of connection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.  To connect to a MS Access database take a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023861/how-to-connect-access-database-in-c-sharp.

Answer (score 3):

You should try create the SqlCommand with:

```
SqlCommand xp = CustomerInfo.CreateCommand();
```

See this example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update:**

Try use `OleDbConnection`. See:

```
public DataSet GetDataSetFromAdapter(
    DataSet dataSet, string connectionString, string queryString)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection =
               new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter =
            new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

        // Set the parameters.
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
            "@CategoryName", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "toasters";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
            "@SerialNum", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 239;

        // Open the connection and fill the DataSet. 
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the 
        // code exits the using block.
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

See more details in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice Renatto Machado! I am still getting the same error though. For some reason it will not connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to use a local database or auto-named database: Here is the syntax for your connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
AttachDbFilename=Your local location here;
Integrated Security=True
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, you will need to specify the local db verson of sql server. Mine is version v11.0.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2010. This is the first time that I have tried to connect to a database like this so thank you for your help.

The Database is on my local machine.

Comment: In that case your connection string with need to use a different driver because you will be using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. Here is a connection string example: connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb;" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Just make sure that your .mdb file goes in your data directory and replace the name with your own .mdb file name.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I will try this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using `System.Data.Sql` as the provider, when it should all be coming from `System.Data.OleDb`;

However, you can use `<asp:SqlDataSource>` in ASPX, to connect to an Access Database, but that is **not the same** thing as `System.Data.Sql`.