# Connect MS Access Database to Visual Studio manually

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-code, autocad

I am working on a plugin for the software Autocad in Visual Studio (C#) and would like to import a MS Database manually. I looked a bit online and saw that you can connect to a database via the toolbar but I'd like for the user to import a .accdb file by clicking on a button from WinForms. Is it possible for me to do something like that? I'm thinking of a library or any helpful tool (like System.Xml) so that I can access the database via code and potentially SQL queries.

To make things clearer, here is an example of how the plugin would work:

1. Open Autocad and the Plugin
2. WinForms window pops up with a button: Import Database
3. After successful import, data will be loaded in a dropdown and you can select one of the values

Every suggestion and tip is appreciated! :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1.  this is a google.  and as Slugie suggested.... after you try some stuff, then you might ask questions.  but first google search hit : (i ean the first search engine result)    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2019

Comment: I haven't downvoted.  But you might get some.  There's already an existing SOF result as well.  SOF is not for "let's reask the same question over and over" .  Its find existing answers...and IFF one does not exist, add a new question.    ~sometimes finding an existing answer isn't easy, but this case it was straight forward : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023861/how-to-connect-access-database-in-c-sharp

Comment: Okay thank you! Next time, I'll try to google more first :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.Data and System.Data.OleDb.
You'll have to look up your connection string for your database.  This isn't a robust solution, but it gets the job done quick.

```
    public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message);  }
            finally { conn.Close(); }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```